# Reading result from radwag wtc2000 precision scales using usb returns empty bytes

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I have to read the results monitored at the screen of the Radwag wtc2000 scale.
That's it. All I need is the get the results and print it on screen. But I only get empty (b'') bytes printed on the console.

Sorry for the bad English.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=1)
try:
    ser.isOpen()
    print("Serial port is open")
except:
    print("ERROR")
    exit()

if (ser.isOpen()):
    try:
        while (True):
            ser.write("S CR LF")
            print(ser.read())
    except:
        print("error")
else:
    print("Cannot open serial port")
```

I expect to get the weights of the pen that I used for testing. On the screen of scale, it says 4.71 on the scale but I get empty byte as (b'')

Comment: Have you checked the settings on the scale (menu 4.1.rS1)? What about your cable? Are you sure you have a real RS232 port? Some ports work with TTL levels these days.

Comment: Yes, I checked the settings on the scale and changed them to USB and continuous but still empty bytes. And also I use USB cable similar to the ones that used at printers. Which is the only cable that makes noise when I plugged in . And I also trıed the Usb(male) to Usb(male) cable but it doesn't even make noise when plugged in.

Comment: The fact that the cable makes noise (when you plug it I imagine) is not definitive proof that it will be RS232 compatible. You should make sure you have the right port and that it is wired correctly.

Comment: I don't get it. Why do I need to use RS232 while trying to connect PC.https://ibb.co/DYGsGVt

Comment: [RS232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) is the standard that your scale follows for its serial communication. On your PC's side you need a serial port that complies with the same RS232 standard. RS232 is quite old, and most current desktop or laptop computer will not come furnished with this kind of port. To replace them most people use a USB to serial adaptor, but those come in many varieties, and only the ones that stick to the RS232 standard will work with your scale. If you try to use, for instance, one of [these](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12977) you will never connect.

Comment: And I don't know what you mean by *"...changed the scale settings to USB..."*, is there a USB port on your scale? As far as I know, the only interface is the RS232C port.

Comment: These images are from manual that I use. And I mean that I have done these instructions.https://ibb.co/sRDzNr3
https://ibb.co/xSJYLbh
https://ibb.co/hdyr5bv
https://ibb.co/7RMjRck

Comment: I cannot see your pictures, the address is considered malicious by my corporate filters. Maybe you can post them in a more reputable source like imgur

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZAhFFaa  https://imgur.com/a/2zv1hre using Imgur requires VPN ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I see... It's different than I thought. And are you sure COM3 is created when you connect the USB cable to the scale?

Comment: Yes, I checked from the device manager.

Comment: I learned that I should send some commands in order to receive information. https://imgur.com/Tburb5x https://imgur.com/ctRowoA https://imgur.com/WmkUOSe These are the Commands that I should use and then parse them in order to get the result only. This is what I get when I run this code. (I know, I should change the "ser.Write(this part)" but I don't know how?)

Comment: You need to change `ser.write("S CR LF")` to `ser.write("S\r\n")`. CR means carriage return and is written `\r`(from *return*) in Python and LF means line feed and is written `\n` (from *new line*)

Comment: after doing your suggestion it printed as                                                     `Serial port is  open`
`error`